# Remove <a> functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen this done before, but I'm not exactly sure where.

I'm using the href attribute of `<a class="classname">` to denote a  specific id on the page, because jQuery plugin I have, uses the href attribute to define which id to do utilize.

Of course, when it's clicked, the page scrolls down to the top of the id, which I really don't want (I want the page to stay in the same position).

Is there any way that I can keep the href attribute the same, but nullify the "linking" functionality of `<a class="classname">`?

Comment: If you don't want it to be a link, why are you using a link?

Answer (score 4):

add the following attribute:

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Comment: Or, you could try to change what attribute it uses in the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).delegate('.classname', 'click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Also if you don't want the event to bubble up, you can return false; from in the function witch is the same as doing e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation().
More info: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: @Nicosunshine: That's certainly true for most cases - but here I listen for the event at the document root so there's really nowhere for it to bubble up to at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Mr. Samuel's and Mr. Ruby's answer, you can apply this to all your elements with jQuery:

```
$("a.classname").attr("href", "javascript:void 0").attr("onclick", "return false;");
```

Answer (score 0):

For jquery, sounds like you need to use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```
<a href="#thisWontWork" class="classname">link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.classname').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//do other stuff
});
</script>
```

or even something like this...

```
<a href="#thisWontWork" onclick="something(); return false;">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return false;
```

will do both preventDefault and event bubling too

```
<a id="clickme" href="#">click me href </a>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickme").click(function() {
            alert("clicked!");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="someLink" class="classname">link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.classname').each(function(){
           $(this).click(function(){
               //do whatever you want
               alert($(this).attr('href'));
               return false;
           });
      });
});
</script>
```

Hope this is useful for multiple link with same class name.